# How to specify proxy server and port with WebClient?

Tags: .net, vb.net, proxy, webclient

```
Using client As New WebClient()
    Dim responseArray As Byte() = client.UploadFile(strUrl, strFileToUpload)
End Using
```

How does the above need to be modified in order to use a `proxy`?  What is the best way to specify the `proxy server` and `port` in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after your WebClient object construction

```
client.Proxy = New WebProxy("YourProxyServerName", 80)
```